# Error in simple android app list adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is my java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView myList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
    List<String> array_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    array_list.add("One Option");
    array_list.add("Two Option");
    array_list.add("Three Option");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main,array_list);
    myList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

}
```

and this is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

When I run my app i get this error

[image: Application Stoppes]

and this is what is in android monitor in case that you may need:

[image: Android Monitor Screen]

This is what I have done so far.

[image]

Comment: I dont have a textview to specify an id?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just refer this.**

You need to only do this `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
```

**EDIT 1**

> What is simple_list_item_1 ?

It is a reference to a built-in XML layout document that is part of the **Android OS**, rather than one of your own XML layouts.

[Refer this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

Comment: There is no R.layout.simple_list_item_1. see my layout file?

Comment: Check it's not  `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` it's `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. check my array adapter code please it's inbuilt with SDK.

Comment: gives error. my layout file does not include simple_list_item_1

Comment: Have you added this **`new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);`** make sure to add this.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi Add **android before R.layout.simple_list_item_1** as this **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi Add android before **R.layout.simple_list_item_1** as this **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111635/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-ali-rashidi).

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. can you please tell me what is simple_list_item_1?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi Please accept and upvote the answer thanks :).

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi Read my EDIT 1 in answer for `simple list item 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing wrong here

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main,array_list);
```

You're passing `R.layout.activity_main`. set your `R.layout.list_item_layout`

Comment: There is no R.layout.list_item_layout ?

Comment: then there should be with TextView becoz i don't think activity_main contains any textView

Comment: What should be with textview?

Comment: use this `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` It's inbuilt layout

Comment: this layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` provide by `Android SDK` so you can use this. [Check this](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/R.layout.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111634/discussion-between-m-d-and-ali-rashidi).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i had to add android before R

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
myList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass,

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

or

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

or

```
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
```

etc...

This may helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much.